How can I create an alert in Grafana based on a Mixed Query with a Join
I am able to create a Dashboard panel that is Mixed meaning:

Query A selects from source 1
Query B selects from source 2
Then we use a join on a field between the 2 queries

View of transform:

What I want to do is now create an alert when the join results in > 0 rows but Grafana only seems to allow me to create an alert based on the queries and not on the data after a join.
Can I do that in Grafana?
